# Convert array object into object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am trying to covert an array object into object array with matching filterKey and filterValue of current object.

```
[
    {
        "filterKey": "name",
        "filterValue": [
            {
                "value": "abc"
            },
             {
                "value": "def"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "filterKey": "status",
        "filterValue": [
            {
                "value": "active"
            },
            {
                "value": "pending"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The result I am expecting as below:

```
{
    "name": [
        "abc",
        "def"
    ],
    "statuses": [
        "active",
        "pending"
    ]
}
```

I tried

```
obj.map(item => Object.values(item.filterValue))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) over the array of data, and create a new object, using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a new array of values for each new property.

```js
const data=[{filterKey:'name',filterValue:[{value:'abc'},{value:'def'}]},{filterKey:'status',filterValue:[{value:'active'},{value:'pending'}]}];

// Iterate over the array with `reduce`
const out = data.reduce((acc, obj) => {

  // Extract the key and value from each object
  const { filterKey: key, filterValue: value } = obj;

  // Return the accumulator object updated with the new key
  // and array of values gained from `map`
  return {...acc, [key]: value.map(o => o.value)};
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const oldArr = [{"filterKey": "name","filterValue": [{"value": "abc"},{"value": "def"}]},{"filterKey": "status","filterValue": [{"value": "active"},{"value": "pending"}]}];

const newObj = oldArr.reduce((a, b) => { // reduce to single object
  const values = b.filterValue.map(x => x.value); // map the filter values to their strings
  if (a[b.filterKey]) a[b.filterKey].concat(values); // if the key already exists add the strings to it (does not apply to your example)
  else a[b.filterKey] = values; // else create a new entry with the strings
  return a;
}, {});

// if you really want to rename status => statuses
newObj.statuses = newObj.status;
delete newObj.status;

console.log(newObj);
```